# Azure python function app not doing anything when deployed

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have developed a python function which works fine when run locally. However, when deployed it doesn't do anything when triggered. Just times out after 5 minutes without ever actually doing anything. I have checked all packages are present in the req.txt, checked app variables are all present and correct. Checked python package versions are compatible with the current deployed version (3.10). Does anyone know of any causes?

Comment: What kind of trigger are you using? HTTP? Timer?

Comment: can you provide the code which you are trying and which trigger are you using?

Comment: I have zeroed it into this line `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` which never seems to complete. I have the version set in req.txt to  `azure-storage-blob==12.18.3` and my python version as 3.10. It is a timer trigger function

Comment: As a further comment, it seems to only be when the function is on 3.10 runtime. I have also had this issue with DefaultAzureCredential. Python 3.9 works fine....

Comment: @William D'Alessandro  please share the code How can the community work if provide only ` ```from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient``` what is the exact requirement

Comment: @Sampath that was the only line that didn't work, it would simply run for ever. I had to downgrade the python version of the function to 3.9 from 3.10. The rest of the code didn't get to run at all, as that line just ran forever

Answer (score 0):

I have created Timer trigger function with runtime stack python version 3.10 and model v1.

By default timer trigger function have 5 minutes. if need more time we have to change in code manually by using CRON expression.

By using timer trigger function and also including `from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient` retrieving blob name present in azure storage account container.
**Code:**

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    connection_string = os.environ["AzureWebJobsStorage"]
    container_name = "pavan"
 
    if mytimer.past_due:
        print("The timer is past due!")
 
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
 
    blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blobs:
        print(f"Blob Name: {blob.name}")
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**function.json:**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

**requirement.txt:**

```
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
```

Blob in azure storage account container. check below:

[image]

**Output in Local:**

[image]

I have deployed the timer trigger function into azure portal. check below:

[image]

**Output in Portal:**

[image]